# How to load a form showing variables sent via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to create and load a form that has a script tag with the variables that I send using AJAX and put this form inside a div using html(), so I use object tag like this way.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "scripts/api.php",
   data:{
     uuid: '03249AAV',
     amount: '100.00',
     userID: '111111'
   },
   cache: false,
   success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
       $("#b4").html("<object type='text/html' data='scripts/api.php'></object>");
   },
   error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( errorThrown );
   }
});
```

and my php code that creates form receiving variables:

```
<?php
 $uuid = $_POST['uuid'];
 $amount = $_POST['amount'];
 $userID = $_POST['userID'];

 $numrandom = rand(111111,999999);

 $form="
   <form action=\"https://www.mywebsite.com/payment.php?sessionToken=$uuid\" method='post'>
<script src=\"https://static-content.vnforapps.com/v1/js/checkout.js?qa=true\"
    data-sessiontoken=\"$uuid\"
    data-merchantid=\"$userID\"
    data-buttonsize=\"\"
    data-buttoncolor=\"\" 
    data-merchantlogo =\"icon/logo.png\"
    data-merchantname=\"\"
    data-formbuttoncolor=\"#047AB7\"
    data-purchasenumber=\"$numrandom\"
    data-amount=\"$amount\"
/></script>
</form>";
echo $form;
```

I get AJAX result inside div but variables are empty in the form like this result:

[image]

I also tried to use in AJAX `$("#b4").html(data)` but form doesn't load script tag and pay button doesn't charge and looks empty, that's why I use `$("#b4").html("<object type='text/html' data='scripts/api.php'></object>");` at the beggining. Console doesn't display any error.

How can I make to show these variables?

I'd would like some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your current logic is making an AJAX request via POST, ignoring the response, then creating an object to call the same endpoint but as a GET request, hence no variables are retrieved. For this reason the `object` is completely useless

To do what you want, just use the HTML you return to the `success` handler and append it to the DOM:

```
success: function(data) {
  $("#b4").html(data);
},
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but as I said I tried that before and of course, it shows the form but doesn't execute script tag inside form that generates pay button, I only obtain form but not the pay button form, with object tag this works but variables are empty, is there another way to get it?

Comment: In that case call the JS logic which initialises the button after the AJAX call completes. Using an `object` element in the manner you're attempting is not a good idea.